# Is it "so damn difficult" or "so damned difficult"?

Tags: word-choice

Both ["so damn difficult"](https://www.google.com/search?q=so%20damn%20difficult) and ["so damned difficult"](https://www.google.com/search?q=so%20damned%20difficult) return about 3-4m hits on Google. Though with the latter, Google asks me "Did you mean: so damn difficult".

Ngrams:

[image]

[Related.](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6945/which-one-is-it-damn-or-damned)

Comment: Given that distribution, why do you think one of those is right and the other wrong?

Comment: Why must it be one or the other?

Comment: It doesn't make a damn bit of difference.

Comment: Damned if I know!  !Actually that  might be a clue: if something has already be thrown amuk, use 'damned difficult' (i.e it 'is so convolutedly difficult')... if you instead are looking for an intensifier use "so damn difficult" (i.e. is so 'incredibly difficult'.).  FINAL advice. when you feel like saying 'damn', any word will do just fine in replacement .."dog-gone" difficult being a common one that seems to bridge the gap between damn and damned.

Comment: @tchrist: Do you always answer a question with a question?